# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage::getResourceHelper() in Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract.php on line 534

Tags: methods

Afetr upgration 1.5 to 1.9 then this type of error comes. how to fixed it plz any one help me

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage::getResourceHelper() in /var/www/html/ecomponent/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php on line 534

Comment: Can we at least see Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract.php?

Comment: $helper = Mage::getResourceHelper('core');

Comment: @SusantaKumarDas did you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

TO FIX :check if you copy also the app/Mage.php file to the older one.
Note:You should first upgrade the magento from 1.5 to 1.6 and solve the problem if there are some one , and after to 1.9

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: the getResourceHelper() is implement from version 1.6 CE and magento 1.11 EE, in Mage class.